# Newbie to C++; visual studio 2012 include path

Tags: visual-c++

I installed VS2012 today and started learning C++.

I wrote a Hello World program with `#include <iostream.h>`.

On build I get the error; `C1083: Can not open include file...`  I believe this is an include path problem.

I tried editing the Include Directories in the VC++ Property Page but nothing I try works.  Currently the include directories path has :

```
$(VCInstallDir)include
$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include
$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)
```

Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: pls show what you include

Comment: Can you show us some code ? It would be easier for us to have it to understand what is wrong ...

Comment: The `<iostream.h>` header is ancient, it dates from before 1998.  Throw away the book, it can't teach you up-to-date C++ practices.

Comment: Hey 
I figured out my problem.  i needed using namespace std; after the #include cmd.  the working program follows:

`enter code here`#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 cout << "Hello World\n";
 cin.get();
}

thanks for the help

Comment: A missing namespace qualifier or using directive cannot cause C1083.

Answer (score 2):

It's not `<iostream.h>`, it's just `<iostream>`.

Comment: Hey all; code follows: #include <iostream>

int main()
{
 cout << ("Hello World!\n");
 return 0;
} i tried both <iostream.h> and just <iostream>

Answer (score 0):

For standard c++ headers you must not put the `.h` so :

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

should become :

```
#include <iostream>
```

After that, if you are beginning with cplusplus, here is a link with the standard library headers (and articles about c++). It is a great help to have this website : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

Comment: Hey all;  thanks for the help.  Code is below:#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 cout << ("Hello World!\n");
 return 0;
}

Comment: Is your code compiling now ? If yes, don't forget to valid an answer to mark this question as solved.